# Lua How iterators and for loops are work, what is it?

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua, iterator

- How does it work and why does the loop return values for k, v vars in order?
- Why if I just call the next() function many times it does not return the same result as in the loop?
- Where does the for loop get the values for the second argument of the next() function?

I don't understand how it works

```lua
local t = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

-- prints 1 a, 2 b, 3 c
for k, v in next, t, nil do
  print(k, v)
end

print()

print(next(t)) -- 1 a
print(next(t)) -- why not 2 b?
print(next(t)) -- why not 3 c?
```

I don't understand much there https://www.lua.org/pil/7.html, I asked a question. How it works in `lua` - iterators, for loops, closures

Answer (score 3):

`next` is a **stateless iterator**. That is, `next` is a pure function - its return values are determined only by its inputs (the invariant state: the table & the loop control variable: the key)

This explains why

```lua
print(next(t)) -- 1 a
print(next(t)) -- why not 2 b?
print(next(t)) -- why not 3 c?
```

must print `1 a` three times: Each time, you call `next` with the table as first (and nothing as second argument). If the second argument to `next` is `nil` or nothing, `next` returns the first key-value pair of the given table. To get the *`next`* k-v-pair, you need to pass that key to `next`: `next(t, 1)` may give you `2 b`. To fix your subsequent calls to `next`, you need to always pass the last key to get the *next* k-v-pair:

```lua
local k, v = next(t)
print(k, v) -- 1st entry
k, v = next(t, k)
print(next(t, k)) -- 2nd entry
k, v = next(t, k)
print(next(t, k)) -- 3rd entry
```

note that it is **not guaranteed** that `next` traverses the list part of a table in order (although all implementations do it this way)

As outlined in the [PIL chapter 7.2](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.2.html), a for-loop is just syntactic sugar to iterate over such an iterator (for the sake of simplicity, we assume every iterator returns two values like `next`):

```lua
for k, v in next, t, nil do
    print(k, v)
end
```

is equivalent to

```lua
local iterator_func, invariant_state, control_var = next, t, nil
while true do
    local k, v = iterator_func(invariant_state, control_var)
    if k == nil then break end
    print(k, v)
    control_var = k
end
```

`pairs(t)` is just even more sugar for `next, t, nil` (which may also be written as `next, t`). You can trivially implement `pairs` yourself as `function pairs() return next, t, nil end`. `ipairs` works similarly, except it doesn't use `next` but an "`inext`" iterator which only considers integer keys (and guarantees inorder traversal).

**Stateful iterators** on the other hand usually have a hidden state (usually upvalues of a closure). Every call to the iterator function changes the hidden state; the invariant state and loop control variable usually is not needed at all (and ignored entirely). These iterators behave as you would expect. We can write a stateful `pairs` (that is, a `pairs` which always returns a closure remembering the current position of the "cursor" in the table) as follows by making the current `key` an upvalue:

```lua
function stateful_pairs(t)
    local key
    -- This is the iterator function: Note how we may take no params
    -- since we have everything as an upvalue already
    return function()
        local value
        key, value = next(t, key)
        return key, value
    end
end
```

this now works the way you expected in your example, because the closure returned by this `pairs` remembers its state in upvalues:

```lua
local stateful_next = stateful_pairs(t)
print(stateful_next(t)) -- 1 a
print(stateful_next(t)) -- 2 b
print(stateful_next(t)) -- 3 c
```

and you can still use this in a for-loop. For stateful iterators without parameters, a for loop is just syntactic sugar for calling a function until it returns `nil`:

```lua
for k, v in stateful_pairs(t) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Lua has a few stateful iterators such as `io.lines` or `string.gmatch` in its standard library; making them stateless would require a very ugly loop control variable & invariant state.